# How to turn off focus searchbar shortcut in Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, dvorak

Question is in the title, but here's some background info:
I use a custom version of the Dvorak layout on a Windows 10 machine. This is the layout I use (the internals of a .klc file) [My Layout (on Pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/E6YK8Mpv). Basically, I have changed copy, cut, and paste to be the equivalents on a Dvorak: ctrl-q, ctrl-j, and ctrl-k. This is fine about 90% of the time. (Lots of programs seem to ignore this: pidgin instant messenger being the main culprit. I'm also curious as to why this is the case, but that's a separate question, and one I have suspicions about).

Firefox (and thus Cyberfox, the actual browser I use) handles this in a very odd way: ctrl-k and ctrl-v do the same exact thing almost 98% of the time...but what they do is random and almost seems to at times depend on the website. Sometimes the shortcuts will focus on the searchbar. Sometimes they'll paste. I haven't yet figured out exactly what causes which behavior, and SOMETIMES (but not always) closing the browser and reopening it will switch said behavior.

**Long story short**, I'd like to outright turn off the ability to shortcut into the search bar, or change its keys. Alternatively, if someone knows a better way to get the copy/cut/paste shortcut keys in a Dvorak layout to line up with the ones in a QWERTY layout than what I've done here I'll be immensely grateful.

(Also, apologies if I've committed any SuperUser faux-pas here, is my first time actually asking a question on any of the Stack-Exchange websites. If I've done so, please tell me so I can correct it).

Comment: There is an extension for firefox that lets you edit the menu and associated shortcut keys - that might  let you edit the ctrl-k shortcut.

Comment: @Paul Hmm. I was hoping to find a way to do it without add-ons/extensions, but if that's the only way to handle it I'll go for it. I'll be trying out [This Dorando Keyconfig extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dorando-keyconfig/?src=search) in the meantime. Due to the random-ish nature of the issue I won't be able to say if this solves the problem for a little bit, but I'll respond back if it does. I'd also prefer a solution within Firefox itself, like through about:config or sommat.

Comment: So the Dorando extension has solved the problem entirely, after killing certain shortcuts outright. Awesome :) I dunno how to go about marking this as answered though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Durando Keyconfig](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dorando-keyconfig/) has completely solved this problem across all machines. I wish there were a way via About:Config, but I haven't been able to figure it out if there is. I was led to this answer by [Paul](https://superuser.com/users/89018/paul). Once installing the Keyconfig extension it was as simple as disabling certain shortcuts via the extensions options. (Also made it easier than the normal About:Config way of disabling the "backspace == page back" thing, if you're already having to use an extension).